# How to convert a data frame with a list in a column to a JSON in R?

Tags: r, json, list, geometry, jsonlite

I am trying to export a data frame which contains a list in a column, to a JSON and then save it in a format to share it.

So far I am trying to use `jsonlite` to do the transformation with `jsonlite::toJSON()`

The data frame can be seen in the following image:

[image: DF]

So far I have done this:

```
x <- jsonlite::toJSON(x = regiones, pretty = TRUE) # "regiones" is the data frame
cat(x)
```

And I get the following result.

*I did not put all the values in the console output.*

```
"codigo_region": "16",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "MultiPolygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [
            [-72.3855, -36.9117],
            [-72.3895, -36.9162],
            [-72.3988, -36.9174],
            [-72.407, -36.9237],
            [-72.4077, -36.9285],
            [-72.419, -36.9305],
            [-72.4227, -36.926],
```

How can I save the object "x" which is a large json?

Any other recommended approach?

Comment: maybe use jsonlite write_json?

Comment: As @Bruno suggested, you can do `jsonlite::write_json(path = "path/to/save/your_file.json", x = regiones, pretty = TRUE)` instead of generating the variable `x` with `jsonlite::toJSON()`.  Alternatively, if you want to keep `x`, you could do `base::writeLines(text = x, con = "path/to/save/your_file.json")`.

Answer (score 0):

As Greg and Bruno said, using `write_json` worked perfect.

```
jsonlite::write_json(path = "path/to/save/your_file.json", x = regiones, pretty = TRUE)
```